# How to add different spacing between elements (h1 > p, h3 > ul, etc.)?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble setting up a universal stylesheet where I need to set up different spacings between different elements, depending on what follows that element?

For example, if I have an `<h1>` followed by an `<h2>`, that's going to have different spacing than an `<h2>` followed by a `<p>`.

I can't just add the same spacing after `<h1>`, because it will be different depending on what follows.

The only thing I am aware of is this...

But, in this case, the 30px margin is added after the p, but not between the h1 and the p.

```css
h1 + p {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

h1 + ul {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
<p>World</p>
<hr>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<ul>
  <li>Real</li>
  <li>World</li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to write styles based on what follows each element. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Short answer is that there's no way yet, there are workarounds with `js` tho, I think you should check this [question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) answers, otherwise you could revert the relation by adding the space in the child.

Comment: You can use `margin-top` instead of `margin-bottom`, so that you will get the exact space between these two.

Comment: I've decided to use the sibling selector, and just use `margin-top` as suggested by @SureshPonnukalai

Comment: Is the content dynamic or do you know exactly what will come next?